Objects dissapear when in Editmode und selected while rotation the viewport
if i want to edit my obejct in editmode and have selected vertex or edges or faces, and then rotate with the viewport, the object disappears. i can only bring it back into focus with ‘,’. this is the first time i've had this problem and it runs through all the versions i've installed and opened the file with. does anyone have an idea? in obejctmode or without selection everything works.

Sounds like issues with unsuitable values for Clip Start and/or End.

Hello could you please show a screenshot?
